# /sbin/init does not exist after removing duplicates with rmlint

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub, init, rmlint

So I executed rmlint to remove duplicates on my archlinux, and executed the script it generated. Then I reboot and got the message

> bailing out you are on your own. Good luck.

And

> /sbin/init does not exist.

Also, there was no init script on /usr/bin, so I cp the one from the root directory.

I also tried executing the one from the root directory with ./init but it returns:

> mount: /sys: sys already mounted on /sys.
>
> dmesg (1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
>
> mount: /dev: dev already mounted on /dev.
>
> dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
> Starting version 250.4-2-arch
>
> /dev/sda3 is mounted.
>
> e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
>
> ERROR: fsck failed on '/dev/sda3'
>
> mount: /new_root: /dev/sda3 already mounted on /new_root.
>
> dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call. You
> are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
>
> sh: can't access tty: job control turned off

Comment: Probably because init may be duplicated (in fact, depending on the program name, that program behave differently). In any case: do not run such programs (or delete files) which are supposed to be responsibility of distribution (but if you are expert on distribution policies and linux in general). Other program may have different expectation and so you can have security problems